# Looking for a date to/for my opening tomorrow

Tags: prepositions

> I am looking for a date **to/for** my opening tomorrow.

*Note: Here “date” means “a person to go on a date with”. And “opening” means “the inauguration of a shop”.*

Are both prepositions correct in the example? I believe “for” is appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **for** is correct here.

*For* is used to mean "for the purpose of".  *To* is usually used to mean "in the direction of" or as part of a verb phrase.  You could use **to** if you wanted to phrase it like

> I am looking for a date **to take to** my opening tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I heard this dialogue in an American series, where a character used “to”.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think **to** is not necessarily *wrong*, but it does sound less fluent in my Northeastern US dialect.